How to Transfer Ownership of MS Lists Entries When Team Manager Changes?
I've created a Microsoft List where users can only see the rows that they (team managers) created themselves. This setup is working well for our team managers. However, we've encountered an issue when a team manager leaves and a new team manager joins the organization. The new team manager needs access to the rows created by the previous manager, as they remain relevant to the team's operations. Unfortunately, due to the current settings that restrict visibility to only the creator's entries, this is not possible.
Is there a way to transfer ownership or provide the new team manager access to the previous manager's rows in Microsoft Lists?
Thanks in advance!
